# How to trace/find "lost" emails with log files and doveadm?

Tags: postfix, email-server, dovecot, log-files

One of my clients is missing some emails and I try to find what is going on, but my knowledge is limited. Have asked the server support guys, but they say all is fine and attach just the logs (which I can't read well > ♻️ )

**What have I done?**.

```
root@myserver:~# zgrep name@example.com /var/log/mail.log.2.gz
```

There I see mails, and they get a queue and message ID attached:

```
Queue-ID: 2125915E4BB, Message-ID: <bc5104e0ac13f3a8daf628dc1e0258rr@example.com>
```

Log

```
root@myserver:~# cat /var/log/mail.* |egrep '4525915E4AA|6B02315A8FE|E511515E3FF' |sort
Nov  2 09:48:40 myserver postfix/cleanup[8085]: 4525915E4AA: message-id=<bc8504e0ac13f3a8daf648dc1e0258ee@example.com>
Nov  2 09:48:40 myserver postfix/qmgr[9669]: 4525915E4AA: from=<shop@example.com>, size=297312, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Nov  2 09:48:40 myserver postfix/submission/smtpd[8275]: 4525915E4AA: client=myserver.host.com[123.123.123.1], sasl_method=LOGIN, sasl_username=shop-system@example.com
Nov  2 09:48:44 myserver amavis[4102]: (04102-12) Passed CLEAN {RelayedInbound}, [123.123.123.1]:59776 [123.123.123.1] <shop@example.com> -> <shop@example.net>, Queue-ID: 4525915E4AA, Message-ID: <bc8504e0ac13f3a8daf648dc1e0258ee@example.com>, mail_id: NfX3Lgs8fYbm, Hits: -1.945, size: 297832, queued_as: A3CC315E4B5, 4282 ms
Nov  2 09:48:44 myserver postfix/qmgr[9669]: 4525915E4AA: removed
Nov  2 09:48:44 myserver postfix/smtp[8276]: 4525915E4AA: to=<shop@example.net>, relay=127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:10024, delay=4.5, delays=0.15/0.02/0/4.3, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 from MTA(smtp:[127.0.0.1]:10025): 250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as A3CC315E4B5)

# A3CC315E4B5
Nov  2 09:48:44 myserver postfix/smtpd[8094]: A3CC315E4B5: client=localhost.localdomain[127.0.0.1]
Nov  2 09:48:44 myserver postfix/cleanup[8085]: A3CC315E4B5: message-id=<bc8504e0ac13f3a8daf648dc1e0258ee@example.com>
Nov  2 09:48:44 myserver postfix/qmgr[9669]: A3CC315E4B5: from=<shop@example.com>, size=298519, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Nov  2 09:48:44 myserver amavis[4102]: (04102-12) Passed CLEAN {RelayedInbound}, [123.123.123.1]:59776 [123.123.123.1] <shop@example.com> -> <shop@example.net>, Queue-ID: 4525915E4AA, Message-ID: <bc8504e0ac13f3a8daf648dc1e0258ee@example.com>, mail_id: NfX3Lgs8fYbm, Hits: -1.945, size: 297832, queued_as: A3CC315E4B5, 4282 ms
Nov  2 09:48:44 myserver postfix/smtp[8276]: 4525915E4AA: to=<shop@example.net>, relay=127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:10024, delay=4.5, delays=0.15/0.02/0/4.3, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 from MTA(smtp:[127.0.0.1]:10025): 250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as A3CC315E4B5)
Nov  2 09:48:44 myserver postfix/lmtp[8095]: A3CC315E4B5: to=<shop@example.net>, relay=myserver.host.com[private/dovecot-lmtp], delay=0.13, delays=0.06/0/0.01/0.06, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 <shop@example.net> uLYULOwuYmNdIAAAPVEKtg Saved)
Nov  2 09:48:44 myserver postfix/qmgr[9669]: A3CC315E4B5: removed
```

How can I trace where the email has gone? Would it be possible to search for the email with doveadm? Or can I see, in the logs, if the email has been deleted by the user knowingly or unknowingly?

Where can I find more to know how to read those logs and what is going on? I know mail servers are complicated, but I wouldn't like to just tell my client “everything is fine” it is unclear to me why your emails are lost. Isn't much trustworthy, is it?

Comment: Try to get a more specific description of what the person is missing. There may be a misunderstanding between a) messages never received or b) messages received and then deleted or c) messages stored, just not easy to bring up using an unfamiliar, non-standard and/or deficient search feature.

Comment: Yeah, did so, but still waiting for the feedback. Just wanted to have a look what I could find meanwhile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Users may sometimes complain that they have lost emails. The problem is almost always that this was done by one of the user’s email clients accidentally. Especially accidentally configuring a “POP3 client” to a new device that deletes the mails after downloading them. -- [Dovecot manual: Mail Debugging](https://doc.dovecot.org/admin_manual/debugging/mail_debugging/)

There is a chance that you are not logging individual IMAP actions, so might not be able to track which user has removed a message. If you however learn that the missing messages are all older than X days and one user with access has recently setup a mail client with a feature to discard old messages, that would quickly pinpoint a suspect.

> How can I trace where the email has gone?

You did, you just have to continue as there are at least *four* different identifiers.

1. You got `bc8504e0ac13f3a8daf648dc1e0258ee@example.com` indicated in the Message-ID header, that is what the sending software attached.
2. Postfix first receives this, tracks it as `4525915E4AA`.
3. Postfix hands it for Amavis, which is fine with forwarding it, and hands it back to Postfix. Now Postfix tracks it as `A3CC315E4B5`.
4. Postfix must have determined the recipient is local, so it handed it to Dovecot, the IMAP server. Dovecot reported back that it received it fully, is accepting responsibility for not losing it, and will be tracking that message as `uLYULOwuYmNdIAAAPVEKtg`.

**Up until the part that you quoted, the message was not lost - yet. Keep tracking** the chain until you reach the end of reported transmissions. Dovecot may or may not have tried to store the message, and may or may not have lost or intentionally deleted on user request later on.

I suspect if you search your logs for the identifier 4, you will find a log entry where Dovecot reports what user and mailbox (namespace/subfolder) the message was stored in, plus another quote of the message-id header.

> Would it be possible to search for the email with doveadm?

**If Dovecot still has your message, it will be able to locate it.** Might want to limit your search to reasonable subsets if the mailboxes are more than a few hundred gigabytes, specifics are detailed in the [doveadm search](https://wiki.dovecot.org/Tools/Doveadm/Search) and [doveadm search-query](https://wiki.dovecot.org/Tools/Doveadm/SearchQuery) manual. Example:

```bash
doveadm fetch -u user@example.com 'hdr.date mailbox' HEADER Message-ID 'bc..e@example.com'
# if that is appropriate and properly setup, you might even search all users:
doveadm fetch -A 'hdr.date mailbox' HEADER Message-ID 'bc..e@example.com'
```

If the message was delivered, then lost, the type of mail storage and the users with permissions might be relevant in further inquiry. For potential follow-up questions about ways a mailbox might have gotten corrupted or inaccessible, be sure to include relevant configuration, such as dumped by the `doveconf -n` command.

Comment: Thank you very much! This helps a lot. I have searched in the mail.log for uLYULOwuYmNdIAAAPVEKtg and found
Nov  2 09:48:44 myserver dovecot: lmtp(shop@example.com): uLYULOwuYmNdIAAAPVEKtg: sieve: msgid=<bc8504e0ac13f3a8daf648dc1e0258ee@example.com>: marked message to be discarded if not explicitly delivered (discard action)
So, looks like it was a victim to one of the spam rules, isn't it? doveadm wasn't able to find anything.

Comment: `sieve` refers to the filtering rules (may be setup by the admin, the user via ManageSieve, or both in conjunction). Search your Dovecot configuration for that term, that will tell you at what path you can review the rule files. Yes, very likely it just unconditionally trusted some note that Amavis left in the message headers. Bad idea, moving them to a folder that is setup to be automatically clear messages *after some safety delay* is much nicer for the unavoidable mistakes in the by nature imperfect spam rules.

Comment: Indeed, have change discard to fileinto a Junk folder. Thanks again for your help!